# Error looping through autoregression outputs

Tags: r, for-loop, arima

I'm trying to create an autoregression model for an already differenced time-series.

I'd like to put the code below in a loop so it's not repetitive.

```
gas_ar_date <- arima(diff_gas[[1]], order = c(1, 0, 0))
print("AR for Date")
gas_ar_date
print("******************************************")

gas_ar_change <- arima(diff_gas[[2]], order = c(1, 0, 0))
print("AR for Currency Change")
gas_ar_change
print("******************************************")

gas_ar_domestic <- arima(diff_gas[[3]], order = c(1, 0, 0))
print("AR for UK Domestic Production")
gas_ar_domestic
print("******************************************")

gas_ar_import <- arima(diff_gas[[4]], order = c(1, 0, 0))
print("AR for Import")
gas_ar_import
print("******************************************")
```

However, when I try:

```
for (i in 1:8) {
  gas_ar[i] <- arima(diff_gas[[i]], order = c(1, 0, 0))
  gas_ar[i]
}
```

I get the error:

```
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement lengthnumber of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

**How could a create a loop in this case and get the full output of the ARIMA autoregression model?**

Here's a glance of the data:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `str(fit1)` it will should it's a "List of 14"

So either

```
gas_ar[[i]] <- arima(diff_gas[[i]], order = c(1, 0, 0))
```

or

```
gas_ar[i] <- list(arima(diff_gas[[i]], order = c(1, 0, 0)))
```

should work.

Comment: Nothing is being printed when I do: ```for (i in 1:8) {
  gas_ar[[i]] <- arima(diff_gas[[i]], order = c(1, 0, 0))
  gas_ar[[i]]
}```

Comment: Use `print(gas_ar[[i]])`. This is a different problem to above. `for (i in 1:8) {i}` will not have anything printed as well. Some default functions return invincibly.

Comment: I am wandering why you haven't accepted this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a R specialist but looks like you can do the following:

```
list<-c('date','change','domestic','import')

for (i in 1:4) {
   paste('gas_ar',list[i],sep="") <- arima(diff_gas[[i]], order = c(1, 0, 0))
}
```